# MySQL JOIN подскажите как правильно построить запрос

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

Есть 3 таблицы.
В первой nv_product_composition хранится id продукта и id ингредиента
Во второй nv_ingredients хранится картинка
И в третей nv_ingredients_description хранится название ингредиента на разных языках

Я написал вот такой запрос на получение списка ингредиентов по id продукта

```
$sql = "SELECT nv_product_composition.id_product, nv_product_composition.id_ingredients,
            nv_ingredients.id, nv_ingredients.img, nv_ingredients_description.title
            FROM nv_product_composition

            INNER JOIN nv_ingredients
            ON nv_product_composition.id_product = nv_ingredients.id

            INNER JOIN nv_ingredients_description
            ON nv_ingredients.id = nv_ingredients_description.id_ingredients

            WHERE nv_product_composition.id_product = ? AND nv_ingredients_description.id_lang = ? ";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(1, $product);
    $result->bindParam(2, $lang);
    $result->execute();
    $ingredients = array();
    $i = 0;
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $ingredients[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $ingredients[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
        $ingredients[$i]['img'] = $row['img'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $ingredients;
```

Я получаю список но не всех ингредиентов, а только одного который повторяется такое кол-во раз, сколько было назначено ингредиентов продукту

```
"ingredients": [
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "title": "Фунчоза",
        "img": "/uploads/images/ingredients/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0.jpg"
    }
```

В итоге я не могу понять почему так происходит. 
Что делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Если вы хотите получить все элементы, зачем вам условие `WHERE` ?

Comment: @НиколайГабараев
мне нужно из таблицы nv_product_composition получить все id  ингредиентов  где поле nv_product_composition.id_product = id продукта, а потом по id ингредиентов из таблицы nv_ingredients получить id и картинки, а дальше по id полученному из  nv_ingredients получить описание из таблицы nv_ingredients_description где nv_ingredients_description.id_ingredients = nv_ingredients.id

Comment: Уберите `Where` и попробуйте `Left Join`